# AWK remove everything after domain and substitute column

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following sample file and looking to remove everything after the domain name and replace column 2 with 4.

Sample file

```
one two three www.four.com
abc def ghi www.jkl.com
lion zebra eagle www.fish.com/sardines/shop
house building room https://www.kitchen.co.uk/something/or/other
plane car motorbike http://www.sheep.org/my/farm/yard/
```

The end result should be:

```
one www.four.com three www.four.com
abc www.jkl.com ghi www.jkl.com
lion www.fish.com eagle www.fish.com/sardines/shop
house www.kitchen.co.uk room https://www.kitchen.co.uk/something/or/other
plane www.sheep.org motorbike http://www.sheep.org/my/farm/yard/
```

Alternatively, column 2 can just contain domain.com or domain.co.uk. The http, https and www doesn't matter. Column 4 doesn't have to be preserved.

It feels like I'm close with this...

`awk -F'[ ]' '{gsub(/\/.*/,"",$4); $2=$4; print}' sample`

...but it yields:

```
one www.four.com three www.four.com
abc www.jkl.com ghi www.jkl.com
lion www.fish.com eagle www.fish.com
house https: room https:
plane http: motorbike http:
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split the URL by slashes, the domain is either in the 1st or the 3rd part; and you can find out where it is by checking whether the URL has a protocol prefix or not. So, this should work:

```
awk '{ split($4,a,/\//); $2=a[a[1]~/^[a-z]+:/?3:1] } 1' file
```

Comment: Incredibly clever use of the ternary operator, but I think you owe the man a few explanatory words =} ... took me a few minutes to figure out what you did there.

Comment: @tink Thanks for the compliment, it's not that complex though; a[1] has either the protocol (http: or https:), or the domain name, `a[1]~/^[a-z]:/` evaluates to true if the former is the case, and a[3] is assigned to $2, otherwise a[1] is the result of that expression. Depending on the variety of the URL forms in the input, it might fail, of course.

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you very much. That works! I really appreciate the explanation too.